# $\gamma^5$ factor in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, dirac-matrices

I have a problem with interpretation of $\gamma^5$ factor in the interaction Hamiltonian. I know that $\frac{1\pm\gamma^5}{2}$ is a helicity projection and it requires helicity conservation in scattering process. But what does single $\gamma^5$ mean?

My interaction Hamiltonian: 
$$\mathcal{H}_I=\varphi\bar{\psi_b}A\psi_a$$
I have two cases, one when $A=1$ and one when $A=i\gamma^5$. After long time I've got quite simple first-order perturbation theory for $A=1$. But what about $\gamma^5$? (I have to describe a decay of a particle into b and $\varphi$ particles. $a$ and $b$ are fermions, $\varphi$ is spinless).

I will appreciate any help, or even better, any title of handbook with similar case.

Answer (score 1):

If $A \propto \gamma^5$, your interaction is "pseudoscalar" and the energy changes sign under parity transformations.  See e.g. Peskin & Schroeder §3.4.

Comment: In 3.4 chapter we have only description of $\gamma^5$ as a helicity operator. I still don't see how it works in interaction hamiltonian.

Comment: What do you know about psuedoscalars?